# Lodash match string to object

Tags: javascript, object, lodash

I'm new to using Lodash so I apologise if the question is trivial.

I have a string and I have to validate it against a collection.

```
var x = 'foo'

var myObject = {
   one: 'bar',
   two: 'foo',
   three: 'wiz'
}
```

How do I compare the value of `x` against the value of `one`, `two` and `three` using Lodash (or plain JS if it's more convenient) to find if there's a match or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use `Lodash` for this example, you can use `includes` method:

```
_.includes(myObject, x)
```

> Checks if value is in collection.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get an object's keys and check if there is one or more keys in use by using [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
var x = 'foo'

var myObject = {
   one: 'bar',
   two: 'foo',
   three: 'wiz'
}

var hasAnyKeyThatMatchesx = Object.keys(myObject).some(function(k){ return myObject[k] === x });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop the properties of an object with `for ... in` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)):

```
var x = 'foo';

var myObject = {
    one: 'bar',
    two: 'foo',
    three: 'wiz'
}

function containsValue(obj, value) {

    for (var prop in myObject) {
        if(x === myObject[prop]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

console.log(containsValue(myObject, x));
```

This is just plain js.

Answer (score 0):

find key by value
`_.findKey(myObject, (row) => row === x ) // returns "two"`

just check if value exist: `_.includes(myObject, x) // returns true`